# Weasyprint does not render images or static files after changing the network connection

Tags: weasyprint

Weasyprint does not render images or static files after changing the network connection.
I have developed a web app with python and Django and is read to deploy. It’s a multi-tenant application which uses Postgres as database. Also using Weasyprint ver 53.4 to generate pdf reports from Django html template.
It works fine with no issues when my system is connected with mobile hotspot for Internet. It loads all the static css files, images from media and everything is fine.
Recently I installed fiber cable service for my internet. And since then the pdf files generated by weasyprint does not load any static file or media image. If I go back to my mobile hotspot data it works just fine… not sure what is causing the issue.
[I tried to show in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t6f0.png)
Same thing happens when my system is offline. Is Weasyprint sopposed to work when system is connected with internet?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem because when I want to load images of my static or css files with weasyprint it does not detect those files but if I load the html only if it detects them.

I leave you the solution I found in case it still helps you or someone else who has this problem.

```
#im use a function with GET to print pdf
@login_required

def PdfView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            #my code here
            html_string = render_to_string('my_template.html',{
                            'my_context':my_context
                            })
            html = HTML(string=html_string,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri())#this is only you need
            response = HttpResponse(html.write_pdf(), content_type='application/pdf')
        except Exception as e: 
            print("Error: " + str(e))
        return response
    elif request.method =="POST":
        return None
```

I hope this helps you as with this I was able to use {% static 'file.css' %}